# Why do failed attempts of Socket.connect take 1 sec on Windows?

Tags: windows, tcp, connection

Working with .net, I noticed that an attempt to connect to a port that is not listened on always takes one 1 second. To check whether this is a problem in the .net abstraction or whether it is a lower level issue, and to compare it with linux (where an unsuccessful `telnet` takes something like 3ms), I used a node.js script to connect to port

- 12345, a port no process is listening on
- 80, a port that is being listened on

Results for **Windows**:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:12345
#3: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#2: error elapsed: 1002ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#4: error elapsed: 1003ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#1: error elapsed: 1007ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#0: error elapsed: 1015ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80
#0: connect elapsed: 8ms
#1: connect elapsed: 1ms
#2: connect elapsed: 3ms
#3: connect elapsed: 4ms
#4: connect elapsed: 6ms
```

Results for **Linux**:

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:12345
#4: error elapsed: 0ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#3: error elapsed: 1ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#2: error elapsed: 1ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#1: error elapsed: 1ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#0: error elapsed: 3ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80
#4: connect elapsed: 0ms
#3: connect elapsed: 0ms
#2: connect elapsed: 0ms
#1: connect elapsed: 1ms
#0: connect elapsed: 2ms
```

Node.js **source**:

```
var net = require('net');
var host = process.argv[2];
var port = Number(process.argv[3]);
console.log("Connecting to %s:%d", host, port);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  (function(i) {
    var date = +new Date;
    var client = net.connect({host: host, port: port});
    client.on('error', function(msg)
    {
      console.log("#%d: error elapsed: %dms, %s", i, new Date - date, msg);
    });
    client.on('connect', function()
    {
      console.log("#%d: connect elapsed: %dms", i, new Date - date);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

A couple of notes

- I also tried remote IP addresses, the results are similar to those shown above for localhost
- in the case of node.js and the way I wrote it, the (asynchronous) connection attempts run in parallel, but in case of .net, I was testing synchronously, i.e. one attempt after the other, and the result was the same: 1sec every time

Any idea why Windows is slow here? Is that some kind of deliberate throttling?

Comment: Interesting.  Have you tried seeing what happens if another program starts listening on that port during that one second delay?  (Also, I take it the remote addresses you were testing with did not have a firewall configured?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Your comment lead me to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@HarryJohnston's comment lead me to rewrite the program to see

> what happens if another program starts listening on that port during that one second delay

And it seems, **on Windows, a call to connect() attempts to connect to an unbound port up to 3 times in 500ms intervals**. If that third attempt also fails, it gives up.

Here's the log of a test run, where I occasionally and randomly started and stopped a process that listens on port 12345:

```
Connecting to 192.168.77.11:12345
#1: error elapsed: 1008ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#2: error elapsed: 1001ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#3: error elapsed: 1004ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#4: connect elapsed: 1001ms
#5: connect elapsed: 1000ms
#6: connect elapsed: 500ms
#7: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#8: connect elapsed: 1001ms
#9: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#10: connect elapsed: 500ms
#11: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#12: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#13: connect elapsed: 500ms
#14: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#15: connect elapsed: 500ms
#16: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
#17: connect elapsed: 500ms
#18: connect elapsed: 1000ms
#19: connect elapsed: 1000ms
#20: connect elapsed: 500ms
#21: connect elapsed: 1011ms
#22: connect elapsed: 1000ms
#23: error elapsed: 1000ms, Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

And the modified source code:

```
var net = require('net');
var host = process.argv[2];
var port = Number(process.argv[3]);
console.log("Connecting to %s:%d", host, port);
var connect = function(i) {
    var date = +new Date;
    var client = net.connect({host: host, port: port});
    client.on('error', function(msg)
    {
      console.log("#%d: error elapsed: %dms, %s", i, new Date - date, msg);
      connect(i + 1);
    });
    client.on('connect', function()
    {
      console.log("#%d: connect elapsed: %dms", i, new Date - date);
      connect(i + 1);
    });
  };
connect(1);
```

Comment: You'll find that it does that for all error codes, but with much bigger timeouts for the other ones, totaling around a minute, something like 6+12+32 or 8+16+32.

Comment: @EJP You mean errors of `connect()` other than *connection refused* result in those timeouts totaling almost a minute? Any examples you can share?

Comment: A connection timeout takes a minute, but if you can set it up you will see it consists of three separate attempts.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article by Microsoft](https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/175523), the reason is that the RFC leaves it up to the implementation to decide what to do exactly when a connection is refused, and on Windows the default is to retry 3 times before failing.