# Delay opening an asyncio connection

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Some of my django REST services have to connect to an asyncio server to get some information. So I'm working in a threaded environment.

While connecting, the `open_connection()` takes an unreasonable 2 seconds (almost exactly, always just a bit more).

Client code:

```
import asyncio
import datetime

def call():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def msg_to_mars():
        print("connecting", datetime.datetime.now())
        reader, writer = yield from asyncio.open_connection('localhost', 8888, loop=loop)
        print("connected", datetime.datetime.now())  # time reported here will be +2 seconds
        return None

    res = loop.run_until_complete(msg_to_mars())
    loop.close()
    return res


call()
```

Server code:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_connection(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
# Each client connection will create a new protocol instance
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_connection, '0.0.0.0', 8888, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('MARS Device server serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Both are basically copied from asyncio documentation samples for streamed communication, except for the additional assigning of event loop for threading.

How can I make this delay go away?

Comment: On my machine your example connects immediately.

Comment: Hm, is it possible that the issue is in python version? I'm using 3.4.2. `pip install asyncio` doesn't fix the issue. Code updated to be runnable without modifications.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this statement `"except for the additional assigning of event loop for threading"`; could you clarify?

Comment: `new_event_loop` + `set_event_loop` (Client)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the problem was in [Windows DNS resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981778/accepting-a-socket-on-windows-7-takes-more-than-a-second).

Changing URLs from my computer name to 127.0.0.1 immediately killed the delays.

Comment: Another warning regarding DNS lookups with `asyncio`: All DNS queries are done using the blocking `socket.gethostbyaddr` call. By default these calls are offloaded to a thread pool with a maximum of 5 workers, so this could become a bottle neck if you need to do lots of DNS lookups (e.g. web spider). Probably doesn't apply to your situation, but just a FYI.